# How can i filter an state array in functional component in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, use-state, vue-functional-component

[image]I have an defined an array as state variable in a functional component

```
const [MessageResultsFirebase, setMessagesFirebase] = useState<MessageCellPropsFirebase[]>();
```

I want to filter it using Array.filter function to update the list.

```
var filterResult: MessageCellPropsFirebase = MessageResultsFirebase?.filter((element, index, array)=>{
       return (element.key == snapshot.key);
     });
```

but it gives the error "cannot find property filter of undefined". 
P.S: `console.log(MessageResultsFirebase);` 
works in same context.Please help i am new with these.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the error is being produced even after the optional operator. And Thanks for the tip. But the main question is as soon as i want to filter the the array it throws undefined can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was happening due to the type declared in the Usestate function
instead of

```
const [MessageResultsFirebase, setMessagesFirebase] = useState<MessageCellPropsFirebase[]>();
```

it should be

```
const [MessageResultsFirebase, setMessagesFirebase] = useState<Array<MessageCellPropsFirebase>>();
```

Hope it helps someone new Typescript.